# Make element appear over another one in a different stacking context

Tags: css

So I'm struggling with z-index and position relative/absolute on a website I'm working on.

The issue can be seen when hovering the plus button (on the right) on this link http://bitgamers.co.uk/thebox_test/media/movie/132/fury

If you scroll down to make the popover appear at the bottom, it shows without a problem but if it appears at the top, it is hidden under the banner (which is a background image).

I've done a bit of research and think I figured that it is because those two elements are in different stacking contexts (banner and poster in the header and the tip in a container below that), what can I do to make the tip appear on top?

I've tried giving it all type of z-index and it does't make a difference. I've put a 5 seconds delay before the qtip closes so you can look at the code.

Thanks!

```
  .media_head_holder {position:relative;z-index:100} <-- banner
  .media_avatar_holder {position:absolute} <-- poster inside banner
   //below
  .popover {position:absolute} <--triggered from navbar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about that... But i think it's because the z-index of banner is highter than the popover... 
I know, you will say that popover has z-index = 9999 and the banner has z-index = 100.. But here we have a trap...
Tha nav you are using (.subnavbarz)(popover's parent) has z-index 50, so all his children will have z-index = 50 (less than 100 of the banner)...
When you say that the popover has z-index = 9999, you are saying that it will have this z-index relative all of the nav.subnavbarz children.. But not more than the z-index 50 of his parent..

I don't know if i am cleary (my english is terrible)

Comment: adding z-index: 9999 to the popover doesn't change anything. Did you manage to get the popover to appear over the banner?

Comment: It's because the nav.subnavbarz has z-index = 50... You have to put popover off the nav to apper